# Plotting data from two files after performing mathematical operation between them

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have

FileSFC1: contains certain data
FileSFC2: contains some other data

Now what I need to do is divide the second column of FileSFC1 with the second column of FileSFC2 and then plot this result. So something of the form:

```
plot ( FileSFC1 using 1:1 / FileSFC2 using 1:1 ) * 100
```

So basically the plot would be a percentage of the columns in the two files. Please help.

Answer (score 23):

Gnuplot can only manipulate columns of data that are from the same 'file' or data stream.  What you can do is use the `plot '< bash command'` construction.  When the argument to `plot` starts with `<` what happens is the rest of the argument is interpreted as a bash command, and the output of that command is what is plotted.  So:

```
plot '< paste FileSFC1 FileSFC2' u (100*$2/$4)
```

This assumes that both files have two columns, and you want to plot the percentage of the 2nd column in each file.  To perform manipulations on data columns, the syntax is to enclose the argument to `using` in parentheses and prefix column numbers with a dollar sign.

Comment: Dear @andyras.
Thanks a lot for your response. Could you guide me that is it possible that I could create a new file containing the first 3 columns of the first file and the first 3 columns of the second file and then work from there onwards.

So some command that could paste $1, $2 and $3 of SFC1 into a new file and $1,$2 and$3 of FileSFC2 into the same file too, with this new file now having 6 columns ?

Comment: I have asked this because in your case the command is <br/> 

plot '< paste FileSFC1 FileSFC2' u (100*$2/$4) <br/> 

Whereas in my case it is ---

plot '< paste FileSFC1 FileSFC2' u (100*($3/($3+$2+$1))divided by($3/($3+$2+$1))) ---

The first set of ($3/($3+$2+$1)) is in FileSFC1 and the second set after "divided by" is in FileSFC2

Comment: plot '< paste FileSFC1 FileSFC2' using 1:100*(($3/($3+$2+$1))/($12/($12+$11+$10))) title   "Pr 60" with line lw 6 lt 1 lc 2 pt 3


The above command gives the error ""C:\Workspace\ConMan\CESimulations\7.plt", line 39: undefined value"

Comment: I think that command should work, but the `100*` needs to be within the parentheses in order for gnuplot to use it the way you want.  The way it is now, gnuplot is probably searching for column 100, which does not exist.

Comment: To create a new file, a command (in the bash shell) is `paste FileSFC1 FileSFC2 | awk '{print $1 $2 $3 $10 $11 $12}' > newFileSFC`

Answer (score 3):

Andyras' answer is the one you are looking for.

I just wanted to add that with this construct, you can't use bash's process substitution`<(`, which is the shame because in most of those cases, you have to do additional stream precessing (grepping or removing lines, etc.)

For this, you need the answer to this question [Gnuplot and Bash process-substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19290333/gnuplot-and-bash-process-substitution), which I'll briefly exemplify here :

```
# Will concatenante FileSFC1 with the first 200 lines of FileSFC2
plot '< exec bash -c "paste <(cat FileSFC1) <(head -n 200 FileSFC2)"' u (100*$2/$4)
```