# gnuplot and bash process substitution

Tags: bash, process, gnuplot

Does gnuplot allow bash process substitution?

In gnuplot I can do:

```
plot "<join tmp1 tmp2" u 2:3
```

But I can't get this to work:

```
plot "<join tmp1 <(join tmp2 tmp3)" u 2:3
```

Should it work, or isn't bash process substitution supported in gnuplot?

Here are 3 example input files:

cat tmp1

```
A 1
B 2
C 3
```

cat tmp2

```
B 3
C
D 6
```

cat tmp3

```
A 4
B 6
C 8
D 10
E 12
```

Comment: Consider using named pipes instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command following the `<` is executed with `popen()`, which uses `/bin/sh` (see `man popen`). So you must invoke `bash` explicitely in order to make use of the process substitution:

```
plot '< exec bash -c "join tmp1 <(join tmp2 tmp3)"' using 2:3
```

In your case with the single substitution the following would also do:

```
plot '< join tmp2 tmp3 | join tmp1 -' using 2:3
```

Comment: you teach me a lot about gnuplot. Thanks! What did you read to become such a gnuplot expert? I want to read the same thing. Oh, and thanks for reminding me about join: When FILE1 or FILE2 (not both) is -, read standard input.

Comment: @tommy.carstensen I read the code, but its not the best user manual `:)`. I found many questions posted on SO very helpful for testing, reporting bugs, thinking about enhancements and learning about different graph types.

Comment: Does the `exec` do anything useful here?

Comment: @TomFenech I don't remember, if it also works without, then: no :)