# Generating plots in Gnuplot using loops

Tags: scripting, gnuplot

I would like to generate several plots using Gnuplot thats why I need to use loop. The data is loading from files "sort'i'.dat". The code is shown below but it doesn't work. I have got some problem with main loop. I don't know why it doesn't work, maybe it is connected with my version of Gnuplot. Thanks.

```
do for [i=0:10] {
  set term png
  set output 'sort'.i.'.png'
  set title "Quick sort"
  set xlabel "Position number"              
  set ylabel "Number on position"
  unset key                               
  plot 'sort'.i.'.dat' using 1:2 with points pt 5
}
```

The error is:
"line 1: invalid complex constant"

Answer (score 7):

This kind of `do for` iteration was introduced in version 4.6.0:

The following iteration works only since 4.6.0:

```
do for [i=0:10] { print i }
```

The iteration

```
plot for [i=0:10] i*x
```

works also with 4.4

One other option for 4.4, although quite ugly, would be to "outsource" the iterations. Only two of the lines depend on the iteration variable, which make this feasible. You construct all the plot instructions outside of gnuplot and then `eval` the complete string:

As an example using bash:

```
set terminal pngcairo
set title "Quick sort"
set xlabel "Position number"              
set ylabel "Number on position"
unset key
set style data points

loopstr = 'set output ''sort%d.png''; plot ''sort%d.dat'' using 1:2 pt 5; '
eval(system('exec bash -c "for ((a=0;a<=10;a++)) do printf \"'.loopstr.'\" \$a \$a; done" '))
```

For the `exec bash` see [gnuplot and bash process substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19290463/2604213). Of course you can use any other program to do the iteration.

But this doesn't of course replace the ease of having the gnuplot-internal iterations. Why not upgrade to 4.6?

Comment: Ok but this "plot for [i=0:10] i*x" works only for one line but I need it for two lines for the same "i" for: "plot for [i=0:10] i*x" and for: "plot 'sort'.i.'.dat' using 1:2 with points pt 5"

Comment: The point was to show, that you need at least version 4.6.0. Which version do you have?

Comment: I have got 4.4 version.

Comment: ... and thats the reason why your `do for` iteration is not working, because for this you need 4.6

Comment: I know that but how to do something similar to this in Gnuplot 4.4.

Comment: See the edited answer, but thats a very ugly workaround. But why don't you just upgrade to the current version?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and definitely the version of gnuplot is the issue. For example, I was working on gnuplot 1.8.10.0  and I  got a message  that I showed in the image 1. Then, I installed gnuplot 5.0, and it worked excellent! :).

[gnuplot sample 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5Qfs.png)

[gnuplot sample 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iG6I.png)

All the best