# GNUPlot - Plot multi file in a single graph

Tags: bash, csv, plot, gnuplot

My situation is:

I have csv file, named LG.0.csv LG.1.csv ..., depending of the source, looking like this:

```
Date,Source,counter1,counter2, ...
02/10/2016 09:25:21,LG.1,4.0364,2.8196, ...
```

I have a various number of this file, I could only have the LG.1.csv and LG.3.csv. 
My goal is to make a plot to compare the value of the counter.

I wrote a bash script to list the files presents in the directory, then plot them together.

```
#
DATE=`date +%m-%d-%Y`
counterArray=(c1 c2 c3 c4)
numberOfLG=4
for (( i=0; i<${#counterArray[@]}; i++ ));
do
column=$((i+3))
gnuplot << EOF
 reset
 set terminal png large size 1920,1080
 set output '$1/plot${counterArray[$i]}.png'
 set datafile separator ","
 set timefmt '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'
 set xdata time
 set format x "%m/%d/%Y\n%H:%M:%S"

 set title '${counterArray[$i]}'
 set ylabel 'Mbps'
 set yrange [0:*]


plot for [i=0:$numberOfLG] '/home/$USER/Results/$DATE/LG.'.i.'.csv' u 1:$column w lp t 'LG.'.i

EOF
done
```

As you can see I use a `for` loop to run the plot for each counter (save in an array). 
This code works fine but does not allow a various number of file.

Now I want to use this to get the file name from the directory.
 `fileArray=($(find /home/$USER/Results/$DATE/remote/*  -printf "%f\n"))`

Then I found many many different way to do it but no one seems working so I get this.

```
plot for [file in ${fileArray[@]}] '/home/$USER/Results/$DATE/'.${file} u 1:$column w lp t ${file%.*}
```

How far am I do it? I get this error line 0: undefined variable: LG (corresponding to the  `${fileArray[@]}` )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get it:

It is weird but `files=$(find /home/$USER/Results/$DATE/remote/ -type f -exec basename -s .csv {} +)` is not a correct array for gnuplot. So here is the solution.

```
files=$(find /home/$USER/Desktop/test/* -type f -exec basename -s .csv {} +)

ARRAY=()

for file in ${files[@]}
do
ARRAY+=($file)
done
```

Use another array, so update the plot line:

```
plot for [file in '${ARRAY[@]}'] '/home/$USER/Desktop/test/'.file.'.csv' u 1:3 w lp t file
```

I don't know the reason but by doing this it works.

Answer (score 0):

`for [a in b]`, despite appearances, is not shell syntax.  It expects `b` to be a single string of words, so you'll have to use a single string. Consider something like:

```
files=$(find /home/$USER/Results/$DATE/remote/ -type f -exec basename -s .csv {} +)
```

`basename -s .csv` will strip the path and a `.csv` suffix, if any.

Then:

```
plot for [file in "${files}"] '/home/$USER/Results/$DATE/'.file.'.csv' u 1:$column w lp t file
```

Comment: Thanks it makes more sense this way. But I still get an error: "Exepecting Iterator for [<var> = <start> : <end>]"

Comment: This is a gnuplot error. Are you sure the quotes do get to gnuplot? 

Can you try to write to a single file rather than giving it directly to gnuplot and check its syntax is ok? besides this, are you sure you need bash? in gnuplot you can use the `system` command and the `sprintf` command to manipulate strings. Loops are done with a `do` construct (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21278243/generating-plots-in-gnuplot-using-loops)

Comment: I am doing a cronjob to run a java app to get data from the database every 15 minutes and erase the old data file and write the new. Then I need gnuplot to generate the plot as PNG. So I guess I really need bash.
The script I put here is a simple version of mine.