# gnuplot: plotting from different (big data) files

Tags: plot, merge, gnuplot, multiple-columns

I have two files with several columns and lines, let's say

> **file 1**
>
> x11  y11  z11  k11  ...........
>
> x12  y12  z12  k12  ..........
>
> x13  y13  z13  k13 ..........
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> **file 2**
>
> x21  y21  z21  k21  ...........
>
> x22  y22  z22  k22  ..........
>
> x23  y23  z23  k23 ..........
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .

I need to plot one column from file1, let's say z-column, and the k-column from file2. I cannot just merge the two file with the command "paste" because they are too big to be handled in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you must first filter the two files before combining them with `paste`. One possibility is to use `bash` and process substitution to filter the files before pasting them together.

Only on the commandline you would open a bash terminal, and type e.g.

```
paste <(cut -d' ' -f 2 first.txt) <(cut -d' ' -f3 second.txt) > paste.txt
```

This would take the second column from file `first.txt` and the third column from file `second.txt` and paste them together into file `paste.txt`.

To do this on-the-fly inside gnuplot (see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/19290463/2604213 for an example), try

```
plot '< exec bash -c "paste <(cut -d'' '' -f 2 first.txt) <(cut -d'' '' -f3 second.txt)"' using 1:2
```

Of course you must changed the actual filtering calls to match your exact file structures, and pick the correct columns. Also, there are many other ways to do this, the important thing is to do the filtering before `paste`ing the files together.