# gnuplot5 - sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected with awk

Tags: awk, gnuplot, paste

I am trying to use paste in combination with awk inside gnuplot so that I can take certain columns of two different files and plot the result. However, I am getting this error:

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I understand that it's unhappy with that part of my gnuplot script:

```
system("paste <(awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$14}' ".filename(i).") <(awk '{print $14}' ".filename_without.")  > Tim_res_".i)
```

And more specifically the brackets before awk. Replacing the filenames without using a variable name doesn't work either while all the command works perfectly fine outside of gnuplot. If I remove the brackets, then it says it doesn't recognise awk, and the command doesn't work outside of gnuplot either.

I've read that adding `#!/usr/bin/bash` might help, but it actually doesn't solve the problem nor does it give another error message. I've never had this kind of problem using such commands within gnuplot before.
I have a lot of files to plot in a similar way, hence why I'd like to make it automatic directly in gnuplot, the `system` command being only here to make sure it works before I can replace it directly after the `plot` command of gnuplot.

Thanks for any help

Comment: `< (` with a space in between the two characters is a syntax error in the shell, too.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake copying here from the terminal. I edited the message.

Comment: See also [gnuplot and bash process substitution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19290463/2604213)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mklement0 has explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43256930/2088135) what the issue is - a workaround would be to avoid process substitution entirely:

```
awk 'NR == FNR { col[NR] = $14; next } { print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$14,col[FNR] }' file2 file1
```

That is, read the second file first and save the column, then do the "paste" yourself in awk.

Moving the awk command to gnuplot:

```
system("awk 'NR == FNR { col[NR] = $14; next } \
{ print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$14,col[FNR] }' " . filename_without . " " . filename(i))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your command, as the error message indicates, is executed with `sh` (`/bin/sh`), which is what gnuplot's `system` command uses.

**`sh`**, which can only be assumed to have POSIX-mandated features, **doesn't support [process substitutions (`<(...)`)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution)**, which are a nonstandard Bash feature.

[Tom Fenech's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43257137/45375) shows a reformulation of your command that bypasses the need for process substitutions altogether.

**If you do need (the equivalent of) process substitutions**:

- (a) Either: call `bash -c` as part of your `system()` command string, passing it the original command (which presents quoting challenges).
- (b) Or: Use temporary files instead of process substitutions; in your case, create at least 1 temporary file containing `awk` output that you then pass to `paste`.

#### Simplified examples:

**(a) Using an embedded `bash -c` call**:

```
system("bash -c \"paste <(cat '".filename1."') <(cat '".filename2."')\"")
```

Note how the inner command is enclosed in `\"` so it can be passed to `bash -c` as a single argument.

**(b) Using a temporary file**:

```
system("cat '".filename1."'>>/tmp/$$; cat '".filename2."' | paste /tmp/$$ -; rm /tmp/$$")
```

Note how 1 `awk` command can provide input to `paste` via the pipeline, but the other requires a temporary file.